# What Are The Changes To OpenGL From 1.x, 2.x, 3.x And 4.x?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

What have changed that makes OpenGL different? I heard of people not liking OpenGL since OpenGL 3.x, but what happend? I want to learn OpenGL but I don't know which one. I want great graphics with the newer versions, but what's so bad?

Comment: Not sure if you've looked already, but [the site](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) has a list of all their revisions, with each revision mentioning major changes from the last.

Comment: What's so "bad" about the newer versions is that you have to have a better understanding of the systems in order to produce a working program. 3.x raised the bar for those learning OpenGL by deprecating Immediate Mode.

Comment: Personally I find IM invaluable for debugging my apps so my projects usually use the profiles that provide IM functionality and only once I get stuff nailed down does everything start shifting toward full compliance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, every major version of OpenGL is roughly equivalent to a hardware generation. Which means that generally if you can run OpenGL 3.0 card, you can also run OpenGL 3.3 (if you have a sufficiently new driver).

OpenGL 2.x is the DX9-capable generation of hardware, OpenGL 3.x is the DX10, and OpenGL 4.x the DX11 generation of hardware. There is no 100% exact overlap, but this is the general thing.

OpenGL 1.x revolves around *immediate mode*, which is conceptually very easy to use, and a strictly fixed function pipeline. The entry barrier is very low, because there is hardly anything you have to learn, and hardly anything you can do wrong.
The downside is that you have considerably more library calls, and CPU-GPU parallelism is not optimal in this model. This does not matter so much on old hardware, but becomes more and more important to get the best performance out of newer hardware.

Beginning with OpenGL 1.5, and gradually more and more in 2.x, there is slight paradigm shift away from *immediate mode* towards *retained mode*, i.e. using buffer objects, and a *somewhat* programmable pipeline. Vertex and fragment shaders are available, with varying feature sets and programmability.
Much of the functionality in these versions was implemented via (often vendor-specific) extensions, and sometimes only half-way or in several distinct steps, and not few features had non-obvious restrictions or pitfalls for the casual programmer (e.g. register combiners, lack of branching, limits on instructions and dependent texture fetches, vtf support supporting *zero* fetches).

With OpenGL 3.0, fixed function was deprecated but still supported as a backwards-compatibility feature. Almost all of "modern OpenGL" is implemented as core functionality as of OpenGL 3.x, with clear requirements and guarantees, and with an (almost) fully programmable pipeline. The programming model is based entirely on using retained mode and shaders. Geometry shaders are available in addition to vertex and fragment shaders.
Version 3 has received a lot of negative critique, but in my opinion this is not entirely fair. The birth process was admittedly a PR fiasco, but what came out is not all bad. Compared with previous versions, OpenGL 3.x is bliss.

OpenGL 4.x has an additional tesselation shader stage which requires hardware features not present in OpenGL 3.x compatible hardware (although I daresay that's rather a marketing reason, not a technical one). There is support for a new texture compression format that older hardware cannot handle as well.
Lastly, OpenGL 4.x introduces some API improvements that are irrespective of the underlying hardware. *Those are also available under OpenGL 3.x as 100% identical core extensions.*

All in all, my recommendation for everyone beginning to learn OpenGL is to start with version **3.3** right away (or 3.2 if you use Apple).

OpenGL 3.x compatible hardware is nearly omni-present nowadays. There is no sane reason to assume anything older, and you save yourself a lot of pain. From an economic point of view, it does not make sense to support anything older. Entry level GL4 cards are currently at around $30. Therefore, someone who cannot afford a GL3 card will not be able to pay for your software either (it is twice as much work to maintain 2 code paths, though).
Also, you will eventually have no other choice but to use modern OpenGL, so if you start with 1.x/2.x you will have to unlearn and learn anew later.

On the other hand, diving right into version 4.x is possible, but I advise against it for the time being. Whatever is not dependent on hardware in the API is also available in 3.x, and tesselation (or compute shader) is something that is usually not *strictly* necessary at once, and something you can always add on later.

Answer (score 1):

For an exact list of changes I suggest you download the specification documents of the latest of each OpenGL major version. At the end of each of these there are several appendices documenting the changes between versions in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The many laptops with Intel integrated graphics designed before approx a year ago do not do OpenGL 3.

That includes some expensive business machines, e.g., $1600 Thinkpad x201, still for sale on Amazon as of today (4/3/13) (although Lenovo has stopped making them),

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL 3.1 removed the "fixed function pipeline".  That means that writing vertex and fragment shaders is no longer optional:  If you want to display anything, you *must* write them.  This makes it harder for the beginner to write "hello world" in OpenGL.

[The OpenGL Superbible Rev 5](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/) does a good job of teaching you to use modern OpenGL without falling back on the fixed function pipeline.  That's where I would start if I were learning OpenGL from scratch.

Their rev 4 still covers the fixed function pipeline if you want to start with a more "historical" approach.